# Unable to upload file by after upload window pop-up JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I have seen lots of questions and solutions on File upload using selenium webdriver on Stackoverflow. But none of the working for following scenario. Indeed the upload window pop-up hang there without doing anything. Kindly advise

Here my code :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);
            //Upload Doc #1 
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='lottery']/div[3]/div[2]/input[1]"))).click();
            //Upload Doc #2 
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("filePicker"))).click();
            //Upload Doc #3 
            WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.id("filePicker"));
            fileInput.sendKeys("D:\\SobetAuto\\5star.txt");
```

Comment: The file picker lets the user insert the file, but if you're trying to automate it, you don't need to open it, just provide the proper file value to the input.

Comment: Hi Neil , do you mind show me the way how to do it ? thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with selenium, just basing myself on what I know from phantomJS and the like.  You can't depend on anything requiring user interaction.  However, you *can* pre-select files on behalf of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see if it works or not :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("filePicker")).sendKeys("D:/SobetAuto/5star.txt");
```